# Why triggering and simulation of button clicking from typescript code in html doesn't work?

Tags: angular, html, typescript, angular6

I have a button component in my `navbar.component.html` as shown below. I would like to simulate and trigger clicking in button `Upload` from `navbar.component.ts file`. When I click `Upload` button it automatically opens file selector for instance on my mac it is finder. 
Then I select the file and it is uploaded to the backend. I want to achieve the same action but using typescript code. So I just want to simulate as the user would click Upload button what will cause opening file selector and then all other activities will be the same as he would click button. Any ideas why it is not working? I did everything as was shown [here](https://dev.to/gloriamaris/how-to-programmatically-trigger-click-event-in-angular-4--3i6a).

In navbar.component.ts:

```
      event.preventDefault();
      let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('trigger') as HTMLElement;
      element.click()
```

I tried also:

```
  @ViewChild('myTrigger') myTrigger: ElementRef;

this.myTrigger.nativeElement.click();
              let el: HTMLElement = this.myTrigger.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
              el.click();
```

uploadFile():

```
uploadFile(){

    this.UploaderService.uploader = new FileUploader({url: URL + localStorage.getItem('current_path') + '/', autoUpload: true , itemAlias: 'file', authToken: 'token ' + localStorage.getItem('userToken')});



    this.UploaderService.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item:any, response:any , status:any, headers:any) => {

            this.UploaderService.displayAllFiles();
            this.ExecuteWhenSidebarClose();
        }

                this.UploaderService.uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = (item) => {
        item.withCredentials = false;
}


this.UploaderService.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (item) => {
  // item.method = "PUT";
  item.withCredentials = false;
}

}
```

In navbar.component.html:

```
<li class='nav-item sidebar-false-upload' *ngIf="isCloud() && !sidebarVisible">
  <label #myTrigger id="trigger" (click)="this.uploadFile()" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="navbarToggler" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    class="pretty-file nav-link">
    <i class="nc-icon nc-cloud"></i>Upload

    <div id="fileSelector">
      <input type="file" name="fileUplaod" id="fileUpload" multiple ng2FileSelect [uploader]="this.UploaderService.uploader">
    </div>
  </label>
</li>
```

Comment: Did you check if it is working without ng2FileSelect directive  ?

Comment: @jakubm Sorry for my late response, I didn't notice your answer. When I remove `ng2FileSelect` form my HTML I get `Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'uploader' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("               <input type="file" name="fileUplaod" id="fileUpload"
                      multiple  [ERROR ->][uploader]="this.UploaderService.uploader" >
                  </div>
  </label>
"): ng:///AppModule/NavbarComponent.html@197:32`. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You got this error becasue uploader is directive from ng2FileSelect to remove this error you need to remove it too. I just want to check if it will work without ng2FileSelect directive

Comment: @jakubm So what can I do now?

Comment: I suggest to first remove all things related to ng2FileSelect and then see if it is still not working. The best thing would be to prepare [MCVe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @jakubm When I remove `multiple ng2FileSelect [uploader]="this.UploaderService.uploader"` uploading doesn't work however after clicking upload button there is displayed finder file selector. However when I try to execute it from the typescript as shown above it even doesn't display file selector window. Do you have any other suggestions?